# How to create a simple distributed Map for Java application?

Tags: java, caching, distributed

I am looking for a Map to share information between two instances of a Java web application running on separate machines. Reads and writes to this map need to be very fast and don't have to be transactional i.e. its ok if one instance has stale data for a while.

Any recommendations?

I need to keep track of the last time a user did something in the application, so its not terribly bad if this information is out of date. Speed and ease of use are important. I don't want writes to the Map to impact response times.

Comment: I am using Spring, so things that play nicely with Spring will be easier for me to use.

Comment: A database?  Or have you tried and it was too slow?

Comment: I don't want to add an extra update/insert to almost every request if I can help it

Comment: +1 for a database. Why would you do this via the file system? Are there any business requirements that force you to use the file system? Are you aware that you might lose platform independence?

Comment: Well, if you need it?  The right database can be very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try Hazelcast, JGroups or Ehcache. All support a distributed map.

EDIT: Another option is to use RMI top a service running in one or the other JVM.  This avoids the need for an additional library.

Comment: The Hazelcast Map is transactional and guarantees that I won't get stale data. Thats overkill for my application. I think EHCache requires a separate cache VM so thats no good. JGroups seems to be more of a toolkit for building this stuff yourself, which is something I hope to avoid. The ReplicatedHashMap in JGroups is flagged as "not for production" in the documentation.

Comment: AFAIK, EHcache only requires a separate JVM in case you want persistence even if all the JVMs shut down. It can use JGroups and acts as additional functionality to ReplicateHashMap.

Comment: If you start a transaction then Hazelcast Map will be transactional. Don't start transaction and simply use map.put/get/remove it won't use transaction at all. Try it, the love is guaranteed :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, there is [Memcached](http://memcached.org/)  which is very robust and proven over the time.

Comment: It would be nice to not have to install any additional services on the machines though, so a pure Java solution is preferred

Comment: Then I would recommend to go with Ehcache as suggested by Peter earlier. It has inherent distributed feature.