# Is there a standard way of synchronising a Map of objects across a network?

Tags: java, network-programming, synchronization

In Java, I have a HashMap containing objects (which can be serializable, if it helps). Elsewhere on a network, I have another HashMap in another copy of the application that I would like to stay in sync with the first.

For example if on computer A, someone runs `myMap.put("Hello", "World");` and on computer B, someone runs `myMap.put("foo", "bar");`, then after some time delay for changes to propagate, both computers would have `mayMap.get("Hello") == "World"` and `mayMap.get("foo") == "bar"`.

Is this requirement met by an existing facility in the Java language, a library, or some other program? If this is already a "solved problem" it would be great not to have to write my own code for this.

If there are multiple ways of achieving this I would prefer, in priority order:

1. Changes are guaranteed to propagate 100% of the time (doesn't matter how long it takes)
2. Changes propagate rapidly
3. Changes propagate with minimal bandwidth use between computers.

(Note: I have had trouble searching for solutions as results are dominated by questions about synchronizing access to a Map from multiple threads in the same application. This is *not* what my question is about.)

Comment: Have you considered using a common database on some shared server?

Comment: the magic word to search for is "distributed", and that is indeed solved by databases, distributed filesystems, ...

Comment: @zapl You're right, using "distributed" in my query throws up [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304291/how-to-create-a-simple-distributed-map-for-java-application) that addresses the same need.
What's the SO protocol - should I delete my question now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at the `hazelcast` in-memory database.

It's an open source solution designed for distributed architectures.

It maps really well to your problem since the hazelcast `IMap` extends `java.util.Map`.

Link: [Hazelcast IMap](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is call clustering between two node

here i have some solution

1. you can achieve your requirement using **serialization** make your map
   serializable    read and write  state of map in each interval of time
   and sync it.this is core and basic      way to achieve your
   functionality.but by using serialization you have to manually manage
       sync of map(i.e you have to do code for that)
2. [**Hazelcast**](http://hazelcast.org/getting-started/) open source distributed caching mechanism    hazelcast
   is best api and have reach libarary to achive cluster environment
   and share      data between different node
3. [**coherence web**](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Coherence) also provide mechanism to achieve clustering by
   Oracle
4. [**Ehcache**](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/get-started/introduction) is a cache library introduced in 2003 to improve
   performance by reducing the load on underlying resources. Ehcache is
   not for both general-purpose caching and caching Hibernate
   (second-level cache), data access objects, security credentials, and
   web pages. It can also be used for SOAP and RESTful server caching,
   application persistence, and distributed caching

among all of above **Hazelcast** is best api go through it will sure help you

Comment: +1 good answer. have you got any experience with inifinispan?

Comment: Oracle Coherence is a much better solution. Faster, more scalable, better capabilities, more stable, more complete. The only down-side is that it is a commercial product.